# php explode is not working well

Tags: php, explode

Please help me out with my code. **[explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)** didnt work for me.

What I need is to insert all those seperated words into an array "`$traceData`" so I can access them by the array index. (`$traceData[1]`,`$traceData[2]`...)

My `$_GET[allTrace]` is:

`Quality|good|bad|reason\nQuality2|good2|bad2|reason2\nQuality3|good3|bad3|reason3\n`

```
$allTrace = explode("\n",$_GET[allTrace]);

foreach ($allTrace as $value) {

$row = explode("|", $value);

    foreach($row as $traceData) {

        mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO trace VALUES (null, '$_COOKIE[user011]', '$traceData[0]', '$traceData[1]','$traceData[2]', $date, '$traceData[3]', '$_GET[page]')"); 

    }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: `$allTrace = explode("\n",$_GET[allTrace]);`  need to be `$allTrace = explode('\n',$_GET['allTrace']);` check once

Comment: `$allTrace = explode("\n",$_GET[allTrace]);` no sense. Write it **`$allTrace = explode("\n",$_GET["allTrace"]);`**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have one too many for loops there, your $row will contain what you want.

```
$string = "Quality|good|bad|reason\nQuality2|good2|bad2|reason2\nQuality3|good3|bad3|reason3\n";

$allTrace = explode("\n",$string);

foreach ($allTrace as $value) {
$row = explode("|", $value);
    print_r($row);
}
```

You will then notice for the first iteration of the foreach that

```
$row = Array ( [0] => Quality [1] => good [2] => bad [3] => reason )
```

So what you want to have is:

```
$allTrace = explode("\n",$_GET[allTrace]);

foreach ($allTrace as $value) {

    $traceData = explode("|", $value);

    mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO trace VALUES (null, '$_COOKIE[user011]', '$traceData[0]', '$traceData[1]','$traceData[2]', $date, '$traceData[3]', '$_GET[page]')"); 
}
```